# Update a Scheduled Task Action Argument using Powershell 4.0

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, taskscheduler

Does anyone know how to update the **Arguments** of a Scheduled Task Action using PowerShell?

Here is how I have been told to update the Action, thanks to [@Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2215029/richard) 's answer in another question.

```
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe"
Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName "YourTaskName" -Action $Action
```

What do I need to add to this so I can also change the Argument and I suppose whilst we are here, the Start In option as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `-Argument` parameters to add an argument string to an action. And use the `-WorkingDirectory` parameter to add a `Start In` option.

```
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument 'Arg1 Arg2' -WorkingDirectory "C:\StartInThisFolder\"
```

Comment: Thanks again @Richard. I don't see why I can't find such simple information using google :P

Comment: @GarethDoherty A hand trick is to use the `Help` cmdlet e.g. `help New-ScheduledTaskAction -full` will give you all the syntax. If you need a command and you dont know what its called can use `Get-command "*Task*"` This will get any cmdlets to do with tasks.

Comment: Sorry I am back again. `Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName "YourTaskName" -TaskPath "\ScheduledJobs\Non-Live\ -Action $Action`

Comment: Sorry, I cannot amend that comment. but `Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName "YourTaskName" -TaskPath "\ScheduledJobs\Non-Live\" -Action $Action` why does I get and **The specified path is invalid.** The Task Path exists :(

Comment: Create the Task manually in the location that you want it. Then run `Get-ScheduledTask` and look to see what the `TaskPath` is then use that.

Comment: Hi Richard, I raised another question for this here where I explain what I have done [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40001457/update-scheduled-task-in-sub-folder-the-specified-path-is-invalid-powershell)